# Combination of N-number list with M enabled items

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a list of N numbers (boolean), where a exactly M of them must be selected (true), not more or less.
An item of the list can only be selected (1) or not selected (0).

Example with N=4, M=3:

- [0,1,1,1] -> OK
- [1,0,1,1] -> OK
- [1,1,1,1] -> not OK because more than M items are selected
- [0,1,1,0] -> not OK because less than M items are selected

Or with N=4, M=2, if I didn't forget any, there is 6 combinations: 1100,1010,1001,0101,0110,0011

A more realistic example, in my case, could be N=40, M=30.

How many possible combinations exists?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The number of permutations; just edited, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just the binomial coefficient given by the formula $\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-k+1)}{k\times(k-1)\dots \times1}$

However, if it is ok to save all of the answers in an array you can use Pascal's recurrence instead:

```
#include <cstdio>
long long binomial [60][60];
int main(){
  long long n,m;
  for(n=0;n<100;n++){
    binomial[n][0]=1;
  }
  for(n=1;n<60;n++){
    for(m=1;m<60;m++){
      binomial[n][m]=binomial[n-1][m]+binomial[n-1][m-1];
    }
  }
  scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);
  printf("%lld\n",binomial[n][m]);
}
```

The c++ code above stores all the values with $N,M<60$ and prints a desired such value.